# Facebook Restriction and Friends of Friends

Tags: facebook, friends

If I have my stuff like pictures and statuses as friends of friends, can the people whom I have put in my restricted list view them?

Answer (score 2):

There is more in [the source](https://www.facebook.com/help/206571136073851) but maybe this is enough:

> When you add someone to your Restricted list, they'll only be able to see your Public content or posts that you tag them in. So if you put your boss on your Restricted list, post a photo and choose Friends as the audience, your boss (and anyone else on Restricted) won’t see that photo. However, if you add a tag of your boss to the photo, we’ll let them know they’re in it and they’ll be able to see the photo. If someone else tries to tag your boss in one of your photos, you’ll get to approve this tag from your pending posts.

For [How can I see what my Timeline looks like to other people?](https://www.facebook.com/help/288066747875915)